# enumerated values for protocol constants in VHDL

Tags: enums, vhdl

I have an enumerated type with an explicit `enum_encoding` attribute:

```
type completion_status is (SC, UR, CRS, CA);
attribute enum_encoding : string;
attribute enum_encoding of completion_status : type is "000 001 010 100";

signal status : completion_status;
```

Is there a sensible way to convert these values to and from `std_logic_vector` for use in a protocol implementation? The most obvious `completion_status'value` and `completion_status'image` seem to be unsynthesizable.

The goal would be something that allows me to use something close to

```
tx_data(47 downto 45) <= status;
```

to get the status value out on the wire, and to collect it on the other side with something like

```
case completion_status(rx_data(47 downto 45)) is
```

and having "don't care" values for synthesis here would probably be really useful.

Comment: `type completion_status_vals is array (completion_status'LOW to completion_status'HIGH) of std_logic_vector(2 down to 0); constant completion_values: completion_status_vals := ("000", "001", "010", "100");` You could also skip the enumerated type and attribute and define individual constants for SC, UR, CRS, and CA. As is there is a [simulation and synthesis mismatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psJmJ.jpg) (IEEE Std 1076.6-2004, RTL Synthesis, *withdrawn*) when trying to convert, because the order isn't continuous in the enum_coding attribute and the enumerated type values represent position.

Comment: You could also have enumeration values you don't use allowing positional value to match the binary value post synthesis. You can convert to and from positional values with 'POS and 'VAL predefined attributes (which are synthesis eligible - IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 8.14.1.1 Attributes whose prefix type is a type t). Integer to std_logic_vector and vice versa conversions are found in IEEE packages numeric_std and numeric_std_unsigned. The former requiring type conversions to/from std_logic_vector.

Comment: I have used `completion_status'pos` in the past to connect a state machine to registers to monitor the current state. Be aware though that the attribute enum_ecoding only has value for the synthesis tool - it has no real meaning in VHDL itself. 'pos will always return the integer position value of the value in the enum - not the encodings you set.

Comment: @user1155120 that is probably the closest thing to a solution there is -- basically ignore `enum_encoding` completely and do the encoding by hand, possibly in a function. My hope was to give this over to the compiler completely.